# Algorithm to determine if A is within X of a multiple of B

Tags: algorithm

This is not language specific, but I'm not very good with maths!

What is the most efficient way to test if A is within X of a multiple of B?  The method I'm using at the moment is:

```
# when (A mod B) < (B/2)
if (A modulus B) < X THEN TRUE
# when (A mod B) > (B/2)
if ABS((A modulus B) - B) < X THEN TRUE
```

Example 1: A is 100 more than 3 x B

```
A=30100
B=10000
X=150

(30100 mod 10000) = 100 < (10000/2)
(30100 modulus 10000) = 100
```

Example 2: A is 100 less than 3 x B

```
A=29900
B=10000
X=150

(29900 mod 10000) = 9900 > (10000/2)
ABS((29900 modulus 10000) - 10000) = 100
```

Is there a better way to do this?

(To avoid an XY Problem: I'm writing a script to monitor some industrial machinery, and I want to fire an alert when a lifetime counter metric is within a range of a periodic maintenance value. When the service interval is 10000 and the alert range is 150, I want to know when that counter is between 9850 and 10150, or 19850 and 20150, etc)

Comment: the only change I would make is to replace ABS((A modulus B) - B) with (B - (A mod B))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is not bad, but it's a little faster to do:

```
if ((A + X) % B) <= X*2 then
    TRUE
else
    FALSE
```

That's for distance <= X.  If you need distance < X, then:

```
if ((A + X + B - 1) % B) <= X*2-2 then
    TRUE
else
    FALSE
```

Note that `A + X + B - 1` is like `A + X - 1`, but protected against anything weird your language might do with the modulus operator and negative operands in the case that X == 0.

Comment: The caution in your last paragraph seems a bit excessive to me: since distance is always non-negative, it's not even obvious what the right behavior *is* if *X* is zero and we require distance < *X*. If you want to write any special code to handle it, it should probably just be `assert(x > 0)`.

Comment: I knew there would be a more efficient way. Thanks for your answer; I'm marking it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is whatever you find clearest; but personally I would write the equivalent of ((*A* + *X*) MOD *B* ≤ 2*X*). For example, in C / Java / Perl / JavaScript / etc.:

```
if ((a + x) % b <= 2 * x) {
    // A is within X of a multiple of B
}
```